# SPSS how do you get the value of chi square test as variable?

Tags: spss, chi-squared

I have two tables and via

```
CROSSTABS 
/TABLES = table1 BY table2 
/STATISTICS=CHISQ.
```

you receive not only 2 tables with the results but also the table for the chi-square-test.

BUT this is too much information for me. All I need is simply one text output:

```
"the chi test is fine/ not fine."
```

via sth. like

```
COMPUTE new_variable = 16.92 - chisq_value.
EXECUTE.

DO IF newvariable < 0.
DO IF $CASENUM EQ 1.
   PRINT RECORDS=1
   /"since the chi test is negativ you have to choose a different partition!".
END IF.
END IF.
```

The PROBLEM now is: How do I get the variable "chisq-value"? Via /stat..=chisq I don't receive one single value that I could substract from 16.92 (that is my calculated value which must be greater than the chi value) but a whole table...

Thanks for any help :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use OMS to capture the statistics table as a dataset and then activate it and read it like any dataset.  Here is an example.

dataset declare stats.
oms select tables /if subtypes='Chi Square Tests'
/destination outfile=stats format=sav.
CROSSTABS /TABLES=educ BY jobcat
  /FORMAT=NOTABLES /STATISTICS=CHISQ.
omsend.
dataset activate stats.

Comment: Thanks so far, didn't know OMS until now! However, trying this I receive a new datasheet with correct defined variables, but no data. Any idea, what could have gone wrong?